# How to change variable in a function. (R)

Tags: r, function, variables

I have a PDF which is a function of price. Say `f(p)`. I want to have the same PDF function for returns which is `r=(p-u)/u` where u is the realized price today, and I have it. How can I code this?

for example: (I don't know the pdf analytically, this is just an example)

```
realPDF <- function(S) (1-S)^2
newPDF <- function(r) realPDF(r=(S-u)/u)
```

Is this right?

Edited:
 How about this:

```
realPDF <- function(S) (1-S)^2
r_t <- function(S) (S- u)/u]
newPDF <- function(r_t) realPDF(r_t)
```

Comment: no, it isn't. The argument to `realPDF` is called `S`, not `r`.

Comment: Do you mean `function(S, u) (S-u)/u)`?

Comment: No, u is a constant price. say 800. @RomanLuštrik

Comment: `newPDF <- function(r_t) realPDF(r_t)` is the long way for `newPDF <- realPDF` The only difference is that you are changing the name of the parameter on the long way.

Comment: I think you are asking for impossible. Maybe better to copy the source of the "pdf" function, edit, and save as new function.

Comment: Maybe `newPDF <- function(x) realPDF(r_t(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer it numerically and it worked:

```
x <- seq( min(S),  max(S), 1) # The prices
y <- realPDF(x)  # probablities of each price
rets <- (x- u)/u  # create returns
tmp <- splinefun(rets , y= y)  # define the function numerically with spline
PDF<- function(r_t) tmp(r_t) # define the PDF function
normalizer <- integrate( PDF , min(rets), max(rets)[[1]] # in order to integrate to one
newPDF <- function(r_t) PDF(r_t)/normalizer
```